# What determines what domain controller a IIS Web Application uses for any authentication routines?

Tags: authentication, iis, active-directory, windows-server-2016, domaincontroller

We're running  on Windows Server 2016. We've been having some slowdown with a web application running in IIS. After the software team determined it was not an issue between IIS and MS-SQL, I'm trying to poke around a bit more.

The actions that are incurred delay seem to be ones that send credentials to Active Directory each time they are invoked. I'm hoping to determine which domain controller the app is using.

Looking through some config files, but the only thing I found related to authentication was:

```
    <authentication mode="Windows" />
```

What determines which domain controller an IIS web app uses for authentication? Settings in the app itself? Settings in IIS itself? Global settings in Windows Server 2016?

Answer (score 0):

Which domain controller is used is determined by DNS when the domain name is looked up. There is some logic used to pick the right one, but it's all done via DNS. It's not IIS or the server it's running on that makes that choice. It's just whichever IP address comes first in the DNS resolution. If you want to read more about how that happens, you can: [DNS and AD DS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/identity/ad-ds/plan/dns-and-ad-ds)

But simply: it could be any of the domain controllers.

Answer (score 0):

Each available domain controller responds with a datagram to indicate that it is currently running and returns the information to DsGetDcName. The client sends a DNS lookup query to DNS to find a domain controller, preferably in the client's own subnet. Therefore, clients find domain controllers by querying DNS for records of the form: `_LDAP._TCP.dc._msdcs.domainname`.

You can refer to this document for more information: [How domain controllers are located in Windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-server/identity/how-domain-controllers-are-located)